# Sorting a table into a another table

Tags: excel, reference, formula

I'm sorry for the vague title, I don't know how to classify this issue. An example of my problem is below.
I'm trying to get this:

```
   A         B        C
Ammonia     21.4     12-1-15
Ammonia     21       12-2-15
Nitrate     0.25     12-1-15
Nitrate     0.25     12-2-15
TKN          1       12-1-15
TKN          2       12-2-15
```

Into something like this without always copying it ( there's a ton of data and references)

```
       Date     Ammonia     Nitrate      TKN
    12-1-15     21.4         0.25        1
    12-2-15     21           0.25        2
```

Hopefully without the use of vba.

Comment: Seems like a great place for a pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert pivot table... select range andsetup like below:

[image]

Simple matter of a right click on the pivot table and refresh when data changes.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly it!